# While-loop/ finding sequences in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, while-loop

I have a dataframe such as:

```
                Price   Ticket
Id                            
505          86.5000  110152           
258          86.5000  110152           
760          86.5000  110152           
263          79.6500  110413           
559          79.6500  110413           
586          79.6500  110413           
111          52.0000  110465           
476          52.0000  110465           
431          26.5500  110564           
367          75.2500  110813           
171          33.5000  111240
```

I want to fill a dictionnary with : - keys :we enumerate the number of keys in the dict (from 1 to 3 in this case) - values: 'Id' (aka. the index).

For this example the desired ouput is: `{'1': ['505', '258', '260'], '2':['263', '559', '586'], '3':['111','476']}`

The dataframe is already sorted by the 'Ticket' column, and I want it to stay that way. Why? I wanna be able to use the dictionnary and dataframe (still ordered by 'Ticket') to find out if any ID in the dict is associated with a sequence of name elsewhere in the dataframe. I hope Im clear!

I've written the code below, but I get the following Error: 'IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds'.

```
def same_price(df=df):
    df= df.sort_values(by='Ticket')
    nucleus= dict()
    k=0
    while df.shape[0]>=2:
        if df.Price.iloc[0]==df.Price.iloc[1]:
            value= df.Price.iloc[0]
            n=0
            nucleus[k]= []
            while df.Price.iloc[n]==value:
                nucleus[k].append(df.index[n])
                n+=1
                if n>df.shape[0]:
                    df.drop(nucleus[k], axis=0, inplace=True)
                    break 
            else:
                df.drop(nucleus[k], axis=0, inplace=True)
                k+=1       
        else:
            if df.shape[0]>=3: 
                df.drop(df.index[0], axis=0, inplace=True)
            else:
                break
    return(nucleus)
```

Given the Error, I believe that Im calling the first element of an empty list. But I cant fix it.

Now I understand there are other more efficient ways to solve the problem, but I would like to understand why THIS function is not working?
Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `groupby.apply(list)`:

```
df.index.to_series().groupby(df.Ticket.factorize()[0] + 1).apply(list).to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{1: [505, 258, 760],
 2: [263, 559, 586],
 3: [111, 476],
 4: [431],
 5: [367],
 6: [171]}
```

Comment: Yes thank you!!! But I want to know what is wrong in THE FUNCTION I wrote tho. Bcz I just dont understand what is wrong with the function I wrote. Thx for the quick reply tho:)

Comment: Your function runs fine on the given dataframe.

Comment: Yes, Im surprised to see this example works perfectly!  After a bit of searchin, I get the error message at the 100th index,